# Liquibase: setting the dbms field in SQL format

Tags: mysql, database, h2, liquibase

From http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql.html

```
<changeSet author="liquibase-docs" id="sql-example">
    <sql dbms="h2, oracle"
            endDelimiter="\nGO"
            splitStatements="true"
            stripComments="true">insert into person (name) values ('Bob')
        <comment>What about Bob?</comment>
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

How do I write the `dbms=h2` part in my Liquibase migrations file in [SQL format](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/sql_format.html)?

I have code like this:

```
<sql dbms="h2"
        endDelimiter="\nGO"
        splitStatements="true"
        stripComments="true">insert into person (name) values ('Bob')
    <comment>What about Bob?</comment>
</sql>

<sql dbms="mysql"
        endDelimiter="\nGO"
        splitStatements="true"
        stripComments="true">insert into person (name) values ('Bob')
    <comment>What about Bob?</comment>
</sql>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the Liquibase SQL format: `--changeset liquibase-docs:1 dbms:h2`

Source: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/sql_format.html